# "Object Required" error in IE8 when using getElementsbyTagName

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, getelementsbytagname

I have the following code:

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else // for older IE 5/6
{
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

var url = 'payment/code/xmlrelay.php?t=rates&id=' + str;
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false);
xmlHttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
xmlResult = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Result')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Accessing the following empty XML file from a webserver :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Property><Result>0</Result></Property>
```

or the following full one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Property>
  <Result>1</Result>
  <Rateable>1</Rateable>
  <Location>123 Main Road, Everytown</Location>
  <Instalment>$100.00</Instalment>
</Property>
```

This works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera but in Internet Explorer 8 it returns the error "Object Required" for this line:

```
xmlResult = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Result')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

I've had a search around but have been able to find anything that works. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers
Tama

Comment: Do any of `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Result')` or `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Result')[0]` return Object Required?

Comment: You can simplify the first part of the code
var xmlHttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Comment: Why aren't you using a JS library for your Ajax? In jQuery you could write $(data).find("result").text()...

Comment: Works for me in IE 6 and 7. Haven't got 8 to hand but would be surprised if it was different.

Comment: works for me in IE8. check the response xml (xmlDoc.xml).

Comment: Dan - all examples so far have returned "Object Required" in IE8. Šime - thank you for the simplification, if you could point me to a jQuery example it'd be appreciated. Tim - thanks for testing. gp - alert(xmlDoc.xml) returns "undefined" on Firefox and blank on IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the content type of the XML file. It had a content type of

```
application/rss+xml
```

I changed that to

```
text/xml
```

and it all works fine now.

Thank you for your comments, sorry it was right under my nose all along.